# Convert application/octet-stream content type to string

Tags: content-type, dataweave, mulesoft

Getting attachment ZIP file in REST call response and its content type is application/octet-stream. How to convert it as zip file.
Tried fromBase64, but no luck.

Runtime: 4.3

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to write the file to disk?

Comment: yes and zip file contains xml file.

Comment: can you please post some part of payload rather than image so that we can try t on our end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used below code to transform and write zip to local drive.

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="da388237-d53a-47aa-83b2-96d1ef04489d" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/octet-stream
---
payload.content]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
</ee:transform>
<file:write doc:name="Write" doc:id="1cfd5210-a65a-4ace-9f07-0f575db3a01a" config-ref="File_Config" path="C:\Retrieval.zip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Compression Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/compression-module/2.1/) to decompress the zip payload received.

Example:

```
<compression:extract>
    <compression:compressed>#[payload]</compression:compressed> 
    <compression:extractor>
        <compression:zip-extractor/> 
    </compression:extractor>
</compression:extract>
```

Comment: Aled, I'm getting attachment file data as shown in the image in http response and its content-type is application/octet-stream. tried with as per your example, but getting "Error decompressing: The provided archive is not valid - Archive is not a ZIP archive"

Comment: Is it being retorned as a binary inside a string?

Comment: yes Aled, getting binary data as string. here piece of data "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000#\\\ufffdR\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001f\u0000\u0000\u0000213393_265493_1618241586860.xml\ufffd\u0019"

Comment: That is an awful thing to return. You can try to convert to binary with `payload as Binary` before trying to use the content, however I can't be sure if the binary can be corrupted by character encodings.